# vb.net could not load my swf file

Tags: vb.net

I put a swf file in my project before and it worked fine. but now when i put a shockwave object in my windows form and play it. It gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a DLL you had before?

Answer (score 0):

Should be just what the errors says. You need to add a reference to the ShockwaveFlashObjects assembly/dll to your project, right click on the project and select "Add Reference" or, if that option is not available, select "Properties" and there will be a References tab were you can browse to the dll/assembly.

Comment: When i created a new project with a swf it doesnt give me any error but when i add a swf file in my existing proj it gives me that error..

Comment: That really isn't pertinent information, it isn't helpful for debugging from my perspective or really yours either. Confirm that you actually have a reference to the assembly/DLL as the next step of your trouble shooting process.